# Netbeans WebApp path with a Java Lib project

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

Im building a web JSP-based application with netbeans, called "WebSite". Before that, I'm done with another Java project also in NB that uses Hibernate (with its own hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file), called "ServerProject". This project works fine.

I want to use the classes from "ServerProject" on my new web application, and I've added "ServerProject" in Libraries section of "WebSite". But when I launch "WebSite", it cannot load hibernate configuration file because the path is not available. I tried to copy the hibernate.cfg.xml in System.getProperty("user.dir"), but my application cannot find it.

How can I know where to put hibernate.cfg.xml working file from "ServerProject" (used as a library in my new web application) in my new WebSite project in order to use functions from my ServerProject?

Thank you.

EDIT:

[ServerProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDcer.png)

As you can see, hibernate.cgf.xml is in project path and GestorBBDDLib (ServerProject) can read it properly.

[And WebTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKlcC.png) And you can see here added ServerProject (GestorBBDDLib). Methods of ServerProject are accessible, but it fails when trying to read hibernate.cfg.xml.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you try? Post the project structure to get help

Comment: Thank you Tuyen Nguyen, I added 2 images.

Comment: As I guest because in your ServerProject load the xml using relative path, but you call this class in the WebTest, so that it find your xml in the WebTest instead of in ServerProject. Let's try to put this xml to resources folder in the WebTest or try to export ServerProject to .jar file and the using it as a lib of TestWeb.